# Apache Cordova ContactFind

Tags: javascript, android, apache, cordova

Okay so for the past two days I've been struggling to get my first Cordova/Eclipse project up and running. I'm trying to retrieve the contacts from my phone, using the ful sample code provided on the Apache Cordova website. http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html

But it's not working. I keep getting this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ContactFindOptions". And yes, I have included the needed plugin using the Cordova CLI. I also tried adding it manually, to no avail.

```
// Cordova is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
    // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
    var options = **new ContactFindOptions()**;
    options.filter="Bob"; 
    var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);
}
```

I also included the Cordova.js file in my  btw. I'm at a complete loss here, and all I can find about this particular problem are more people asking this question, without an answer that works for me :(

Comment: I also would avoid using the 2.5.0 documentation unless you are developing against cordova 2.5.0 (which is a bad idea for a new app, unless you have certain platform requirements that are only supported by 2.5.0).  The current contacts docs with sample code are here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/blob/dev/doc/index.md

Answer (score 0):

It seems I'm supposed to answer my own question instead of putting the answer in the edit.

Okay, so I figured it out by trial and error. Apparently sometimes Cordova doesn't update the Cordova_plugins.js file after adding plugins with the CLI. So you need to run the 'build' command from the project folder in CLI.
So when you get the Uncaught ReferenceError warning, just check your cordova_plugins.js. If it's not updated do it manually!

Hope I can help someone with the same issues by providing this solution, however 'green' it might be.